# Плавный скролл по обьектам

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как сделать плавный скролл, нужно что бы определял где в ссылке указан #эбаут. и перелистывал на секцию где айди эбаут.

```
<div class="navbar-nav">
   <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#header">Главная <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
   <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#about">О нас</a>
   <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#gallery">Галлерея</a>
   <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#special">Школа</a>
</div>
```

секции примерно так

```
    <section id="about" class="about col-lg-12">
...
    </section>
    <section id="about" class="about col-lg-12">
...
    </section>
    <section id="about" class="about col-lg-12">
...
    </section>
```

Comment: Множество дублирующихся `id` - плохо. Суть вопроса непонятна.

Answer (score 4):

Используйте [scrollTop](https://ruseller.com/jquery.php?id=58)

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#click").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#about").offset().top
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="click">Нажми меня</button>
<div style="height: 1000px; width 100px; background-color:#ffc0c0">
  Большой блок
</div>
<br/>
<div id="about" style="width 100px; height: 500px; background-color:#9c9cff">
  Следующий блок
</div>
```